# How should I be mixing RCU reader and updater code?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, rcu

I have a boilerplate function that finds a structure in a tree-like database:

```
struct foo {
    struct foo *child1; /* RCU-protected. */
    struct foo *child2; /* RCU-protected. */

    ... /* Other stuff */
}

static struct foo *find_foo(int arg)
{
    struct foo *parent;
    ... /* Do something to find parent. */
    return rcu_dereference(parent->child1); /* or child2. Whatever. */
}
```

And then I have several functions that do something with that result:

```
void a(int arg)
{
    struct foo *bar;
    rcu_read_lock();
    bar = find_foo(arg);
    ... /* Read something from bar and do something with it. */
    rcu_read_unlock();
}
```

And then I have a single updater/reclaimer. It needs to find the object just like the "a" functions (Assume it's already mutex'd from outside):

```
void c(int arg)
{
    struct foo *bar;

    bar = find_foo(arg);

    ... /* make a backup pointer of bar->child1. */

    rcu_assign_pointer(bar->child1, ...);

    ... /* free the old child or whatever. */
}
```

My problem is, `rcu_dereference()`'s documentation says it must be called from within a read-side critical section (ie. between `rcu_read_lock()` and `rcu_read_unlock()`). `c()` violates this rule by calling `find_foo()`.

I'm hesitant to make a whole new version of `find_foo()` which uses [`rcu_dereference_protected()`](https://lkml.org/lkml/2015/8/11/475) instead of `rcu_dereference()`, because it's too much duplicate code, so I'm wondering if this implementation of `c()` is legal:

```
void c(int arg)
{
    struct foo *bar;

    rcu_read_lock();
    bar = find_foo(arg);
    bar = rcu_dereference_protected(bar, ...); /* THIS. */
    rcu_read_unlock();

    ... /* make a backup pointer of bar->child1. */

    rcu_assign_pointer(bar->child1, ...);

    ... /* free the old child or whatever. */
}
```

If this is not legal, how should I instead be mixing reader and updater code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the first variant of `c()` is correct (no specific dereference is needed on updater side), but it makes rcu checker to be confused (the checker expects `rcu_dereference` occured under `rcu_read` section).

The second variant of `c()` is correct even from the view of rcu checker, but `rcu_dereference_protected` is not need: `bar` is already result of `rcu_dereference`.

Another way for make rcu checker happy is to use

```
rcu_dereference_check(<pointer>, <condition-when-in-updater>)
```

instead of

```
rcu_dereference(<pointer>)
```

inside `foo` implementation. So checker will not complain on foo() call outside of `rcu_read` section until it can prove that condition is `false` in that case.

With such `foo()` implementation the first variant of `c()` is OK.

Comment: Great! I missed `rcu_dereference_check()` because its in-code documentation proved too convoluted for a noob like me. [This](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/RCU/lockdep.txt) one is friendlier.